# What is a good language to learn with PHP?

Tags: php

I am in high school and I will be studying computer science in college. I am taking on a national website design challenge and I accepted to be the rear-end developer on the team. I have been intensely studying PHP for the past two weeks, and although it can get messy sometimes, I like this particular field of computer science.

What is a good language to learn that goes, somewhat, hand-in-hand with PHP or is useful to know with PHP? I want to start narrowing down my languages to master, as I suddenly realized you can't just pick up "Sam's Learn BlahBlah in 24 Hours" and suddenly master a language.

Stack overflow might close this question, but I do not see how, as this is not an ambiguous question and can be supplied an answer using facts, evidence and logical explanations, which deems it quite objective.

Thanks

Comment: We won't close it for the ambiguity, we'll close it because it's opinion-based. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: HTML and CSS. These are the absolute fundamentals of web design and development. Without at least HTML knowledge, you've probably no use for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Shane, HTML and CSS are definitely languages you have to know in order to be able to advance further with PHP, next to that there is JavaScript in which you can make asynchronous requests (load more content automatically when scrolling down etc)

These techniques however are not that easy to just learn and use in every situation tho (ajax / async scripting) but general javascript is quite fun and can make your page interactive.

Now if your backend software isn't limited to PHP you could choose to use either Python using the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) framework or Ruby using the [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) framework for webdevelopment.

These are languages that aren't solely based on websites nor are specifically optimized for them but they do fine although it's better to have a framework ontop of them as I mentioned above (links)

PHP is probably, except for Python the easiest language to learn and the most loosely written - as in no strict typing on variables required etc.

Comment: If I were to choose Django as a framework, would you suggest I learn to build web apps with the framework first? Or without the framework? Career wise, would I be using frameworks (like Zend, Django, Ruby on Rails, etc..) in the future?

Comment: I would first focus on which languages are most commonly used to build websites with if that is what you want, if you are unsure of what you want then I would first do alot of raw programming (purely python - no frameworks) to get a feel for the language and to see if you like it's 'style' if you wish. 

Career wise you will come across situations where framework knowledge is required but also where raw knowledge is enough.

Studying raw first gives you the edge as you can understand the inner workings of the framework and build functions yourself.

Comment: In my opinion, the frameworks have a very steep learning curve. There are about a hundred new concepts and technologies being thrown at you and it can get quite intimidating (if you try and understand it). I'd suggest starting with PHP as it is more clear what is happening and will help you understand what fundamentally happens each step of the way between a client and a server (or at least, more so than Django or Rails). That being said PHP is neither modern nor cool and can definitely be pretty ugly.

Comment: Agree, frameworks also have the downside of being out of date for a week or so after a security leak has been found in certain software etc but this however is not thing you have to account for when taking a job as a zend framework programmer or something like that ;)

Comment: http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/  Interesting article I found. But I appreciate the answers. I will continue programming in PHP, HTML and CSS, and venture out into some raw python coding, maybe some javascript, and see how I like it. So far so good. Thanks a lot! @Crazysheep